# Не срабатывает событие изменения sessinStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

При монтировании компонента устанавливаю обработчик изменения сессионного хранилища.

При программной записи в хранилище через `setItem` (нажатие кнопки) в отладчике я вижу, что значение меняется, но обработчик события не срабатывает.

Причем, если я вручную поменяю значение в отладчике, то событие отработает как требуется.

Хочется узнать, почему не отрабатывает событие?

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: 'Unchanged'
        }
    }

    // При нажатии кнопки записываем случайное число в сессионное хранилище
    onClick = () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('message', ''+Math.random());
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // Устанавливаем обработчик изменения сессионного хранилища
        addEventListener('storage', evt => {this.onStorageChanged(evt)});
    }

    onStorageChanged(evt) {
        // обработчик изменения сессионного хранилища
        console.log(evt);
        if(evt.storageArea === sessionStorage){
            if(evt.key === 'message'){
                this.setState({
                    message: evt.newValue
                });
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>{this.state.message}</h3>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={this.onClick}
                >
                    set message
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Рабочий пример через сниппет создать не получается, поскольку запись в хранилище вызывает ошибку безопасности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API#Examples

> if you load this page in another tab, then make changes to your
>   choices in the landing page, you'll see the updated storage
>   information outputted as the StorageEvent is fired.

то есть

> если загрузить эту страницу в *другой* закладке, и потом сделать
>   изменения в первоначальной странице, Вы увидите ... вызов события
>   `StorageEvent`.

Это событие для извещения об изменениях в хранилище, произошедших на другой странице, а не на той, где находится слушатель.